# Laptop heating up (specs: i3-2328M, dual boot Win 7, Xubuntu 14)

Tags: linux, laptop, overheating

My laptop was fine. I usually run Xubuntu, and not the Windows.

Yesterday, I purchased a Western Digital external hard disk and plugged it in, going for a massive backup. Now I started copying about 80GB of data from laptop to disc.

Midway through the copy, I opened Chrome browser and suddenly everything went white, and blue pixelated - graphics driver error. Anyway, rebooted.

Since reboot, my fan's been running at top speed. It vents high-temperature air (some around 55-60 degs) and the mousepad too is so warm (I think the processor sits under it).

Why is this happening? Did that error somehow change my laptop's behavior?

Comment: Did your fan used to speed up & slow down according to the temperature immediately before, and it doesn't now? Any other changes/updates since then? Do you use `fancontrol` and is it running now? Reading from your internal HD (if it's not an SSD) probably heated it up, and the extra power used by the external HD probably heated up your battery/usb power stuff too. Running Chrome then could have heated up things even more and pushed it "over the edge." Definitely check for dust/blocked air vents as Clefspeare13 suggests - don't blow out your fan bearings with 130PSI air though ;-)

Comment: @Xen2050: 1] My fan used to and still speeds up and slows down according to temperature. However, previously if it was running between x and y speeds, now its easily running between (x+ few 100) and (y+ few 100) rpms.   2] MY internal and external drives are NOT SSD.   3] Yep, I will need to check for dust.   However I did not expect yesterday's incident to permanently alter my laptop's behavior. (Oddly, a few months ago, some keys stopped working, and then started working again. Is it normal for a 3 yr old laptop? I haven't needed a servicing till now)

Comment: @Xen2050: Fancontrol doesn't seem to work - Error: "No pwm-capable sensor modules installed."

Comment: @Xen2050, Clefspeare13: Seems a thumbnail generator service "tumblerd" was taking up 99% of my CPU. I deleted it. Albeit with some disadvantages, my desktop doesn't show the picture thumbnails anymore, but the fans are again running close to subzero. :) Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleaned out your computer recently? Quite often dust will get caught on the heat-sink, and if it's not cleaned out every now and again it will form a very thick coat preventing air from circulating and keeping the computer hot.

Comment: 1] My fan used to and still speeds up and slows down according to temperature. However, previously if it was running between x and y speeds, now its easily running between (x+ few 100) and (y+ few 100) rpms. 2] MY internal and external drives are NOT SSD. 3] Yep, I will need to check for dust. However I did not expect yesterday's incident to permanently alter my laptop's behavior. (Oddly, a few months ago, some keys stopped working, and then started working again. Is it normal for a 3 yr old laptop? I haven't needed a servicing till now)

Comment: Seems a thumbnail generator service "tumblerd" was taking up 99% of my CPU. I deleted it. Albeit with some disadvantages, my desktop doesn't show the picture thumbnails anymore, but the fans are again running close to subzero. :) Thanks for your help! I will need to de-dust soon anyway.